# locate cmd how to ignore the windows directory

Tags: command-line

i run a Ubuntu box on my PC, and the Ubuntu is install as dual-system, i mean the PC have a Ubuntu and a WIN7.

So i use the locate command to find a file, it often list a lot files existing in windows system , for example, it usually list some content under /host/.. , those is under WINDOWS. thus not only time consuming, but also make me not easy find what i want.

My question is :How to set the parameter of `locate` command and avoid such a problem? make the `locate` cmd just find files under linux directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit /etc/updatedb.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/updatedb.conf
```

find the line

> PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"

add in host

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /host"
```

save your changes, then run

```
sudo updatedb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo updatedb --prunepaths='/host'
```

This might take a little while to run.

According to `man locate`, and `man updatedb`, `locate` uses a database to find files. This database is modified using `updatedb`. The `--prunepaths` argument stops `locate` from looking along the paths listed. (you can list multiple paths within the single quotes, separated by spaces, and leaving off the trailing slashes)

If you want to search on `/host` later, run `sudo updatedb` with no arguments.

Comment: that is a temporary solution, updatebe will overwrite the result next time it runs.